# How to open specific links in safari from webview?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ionic3

i'm working on an Ionic 3 project with inappbrowser plugin

and i want to open specific links in safari from my app ios

this is the code i used

```
- (BOOL) isSystemUrl:(NSURL*)url
{
    if ([[url host] isEqualToString:@"itunes.apple.com"]) {
        return YES;
    }
    else if ([[url host] containsString:@"aff"]) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
    }

    return NO;
}
```

the link opened in webview shows a clickable item

this is one of them

```
<a onclick="gotoOffer(&quot;Install, Open, and Complete Character Level 5 to unlock this content.&quot;, &quot;https:\/\/jump.ogtrk.net\/aff_c?offer_id=10312&amp;aff_id=39763&amp;aff_sub=f7b876a48d743dedc6bc548908a5cec1&amp;aff_sub2=0vhEVTB6vnEGatmzW%2Fui5r3fJaltF7VRoCNZ%2B1LSy72LdSlDMAG16sCfJIUTWgVmH7nr4mi%2FLg9RQyQmlgpwTY7JBDUtVPgbCCun%2FFqOFeube0vb85CKpcpfX5aqrWb%2FlKYBa7O%2F63dheSeOFBQA%2BA%3D%3D&amp;aff_sub3=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.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.w4baABUDoC31IbsyIcYFdYYH3rWhPSiIdbMMC21RZKeF3C47bQmTAUecD6ckjEZHSRaSTFb86ippA8EdHr19rQ&amp;aff_sub4=&amp;aff_sub5=&quot;);">
                    <div class="offerimg"><img src="https://media.go2speed.org/brand/files/ogmobi/10312/thumbnails_100/thumbnail-90417287459948b60896fe9.08798511.png"></div>
                </a>
```

according to what i have in my code it must be open up in safari because the link has a string `aff` word

but it shows this error in xcode console

```
Failed to load webpage with error: The URL can’t be shown
```

but if the link was just like this it works perfectly

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/aff?id=876">
```

Comment: 1. Log the URL and report the result in the Q. I do not think, that it is a valid URL.Why do you scape `/`? Why do you use HTML-escapes in an URL? Use `&` instead of `&amp` and so on. 2. Is the part that opens the URL is reached? Did you test it in debugger?

Comment: beacause the link who gives me those item it's not mine and i cant edit the links
take a look please : https://www.mobileoasis.net/cl.php?id=f7b876a48d743dedc6bc548908a5cec1

Comment: Did you transform it manually to check it? If so, you have to transform it. It is send this way, because it is a part of a bigger document.

Comment: i didnt know what are you mean sir but there is a programatical solution or not. @AminNegm-Awad

Comment: Did you try it with `https://jump.ogtrk.net/aff_c?offer_id=10312&aff_id=39763`…? If this works, yes, there is a programmatical solution, But first get the details of the bug.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad i dont have the right to edit this page mobileoasis.net/cl.php?id=f7b876a48d743dedc6bc548908a5cec1
and if i make a page with item has the link you give it to me it will works

Comment: Man, put the string you get as string constant in your code and put it transformed as string constant in your code and check, whether the result is different. *After* checking this, you know what th problem is or not. Or download the page and edit it. There are that many options to check, whether the escaping is a problem.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad thanks for helping me
i download the page and put the link in
<a href="https://jump.ogtrk.net/aff_c?offer_id=10312&aff_id=39763">Click<a>
and i click it from my app and works prefectly 
but i need to work with the originale page
mobileoasis.net/cl.php?id=f7b876a48d743dedc6bc548908a5cec1

Comment: To ensure, that I got you right: It works without escaping (i. e. `&` instead of `&amp;`, but not with escaping. Right?

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad if the link inside href="" it will work
but if the link inside onclick="" it will not work

Comment: So for you the differences between the examples in your code is not the escaping, but the element type?

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad yeah right

Comment: So, how do you extract the link in your code?